# Limit lower type bound while preserving literal type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

How can I assert that expression must conform to some type while preserving its exact literal type?

```js
type Foo = {
  foo: string;
}
const foobar = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar"};

// should infer typeof foobar but fail when it is not subtype of Foo
const fooLike = requireSubtype<Foo>({ foo: "foo", bar: "bar"});


// preserves .bar
fooLike.bar;

// this should fail to typecheck due to missing .foo
requireSubtype<Foo>({bar: "bar"});
```

The closest I could get is:

```js
const requireSubtype = <U>() => <T extends U>(o: T): T => o;

const foo2 = requireSubtype<Foo>()({ foo: "", bar: "" })
```

but that requires intermediate function and is ugly.

A solution with single function would be great and no function at all (purely with type constraint) is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but that requires intermediate function and is ugly.

Up until recently, this was the only way.

Today, we have the `satisfies` operator which accomplishes pretty much what you're looking for:

```
type Foo = {
  foo: string;
}

const foobar = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar"};

// should infer typeof foobar but fail when it is not subtype of Foo
const fooLike = foobar satisfies Foo;


// preserves .bar
fooLike.bar;

const bar = { bar: "bar"}

// this should fail to typecheck due to missing .foo
const barLike = bar satisfies Foo;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClAZggLigGdgAnASwDsBzAbiwF8ssBjOK0vBAIwEMyyNNzhEARPjhiANFH5lx8sYwaYsAenUkAFnACuAGwAmUargiDQkOLhHy5e4Hj4UDUAO7aIVU04rEoKjgnYj0eK2gbWAQ2Di5JABkKAGtoFEl7Yj5gf1wKCAD4OFUWTE0oMDICiwA3AqgAOnksRJSIJoESzHZOJ3sUVDkBRQFlUvLgbX8dfWNnVyhgRAjWL1ZkqCM9aCWoAFt-YmoaRslY3qGyJNShTOzc-MKEVSA)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! Looks like it was added in [TypeScript 4.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html).